# How to stop commas from splitting into new cells within a CSV

Tags: csv

Hi there I have a HTML scraper that scrapes information from a website and generates into a csv file, I then use program that I wrote to convert the HTML into a csv format. I need one of the cells to maintain its syntax with out breaking into a new cell, here is an example of the format I need a cell to maintain with out breaking into a new cell

[{"id":"1","value":"https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41-GLGUPXnL.*SL160*.jpg"},{"id":"2","value":["Buy Now","https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wileyfox-Swift-Plus-Smartphone-Replacement-Midnight-Blue/dp/B01M8NAVEP?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAJ76EIXAV3V6D6JEQ&tag=gnod-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01M8NAVEP","new"]},{"id":"3","value":"Wileyfox Swift 2 Plus - 32GB + 3GB 4G SIM-Free Smartphone with Screen Replacement Card and Hard Case - Midnight"},{"id":"4","value":"189.99"},{"id":"5","value":"as of Oct 18, 2017, 08:34"},{"id":"6","value":"5"},{"id":"7","value":"720 x 1280"},{"id":"8","value":"32"},{"id":"9","value":"3"},{"id":"10","value":"8"},{"id":"11","value":"155"},{"id":"12","value":["2"]},{"id":"13","value":["SD Card"]},{"id":"14","value":"2700"},{"id":"15","value":"3"},{"id":"16","value":"Android"},{"id":"17","value":"45"}]

As you can understand this is splitting into multiple cellsany help how I can avoid this separation, thanks.

Comment: Some elements in your json data represented in an array , So you have to take care of these elements.

Comment: Please show your code. Hint: you can use quotes around a field.

Comment: Hi I have tried many variations for trying to keep the value in one cell "," - "" - , how do I surround this code so it doesn't break into separate cells

Comment: Hi @jcaron my code is in the question above, I have tried to use quotes around a field but it still splits into multiple cells (34, possibly more). Maybe it's my version of excel its 2007 so that might be a problem.

Comment: That’s not code, that’s just some JSON.

Comment: Call it what you want @jcaron, JSON is a form of code or data, if your asking for the program I wrote, that would be totally irrelevant to the question. I'm trying to wrap the JSON data so it doesn't split into separate cells and wanted to know how to wrap it, which I have figured out and will post as an answer now. Thanks for taking your time though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if figured it out and it's really simple. I just added `","` around the JSON data like the example below and that stopped the cell from splitting.
`","[{"id":"1","value":"https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41-GLGUPXnL.SL160.jpg"},{"id":"2","value":["Buy Now","https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wileyfox-Swift-Plus-Smartphone-Replacement-Midnight-Blue/dp/B01M8NAVEP?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAJ76EIXAV3V6D6JEQ&tag=gnod-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01M8NAVEP","new"]},{"id":"3","value":"Wileyfox Swift 2 Plus - 32GB + 3GB 4G SIM-Free Smartphone with Screen Replacement Card and Hard Case - Midnight"},{"id":"4","value":"189.99"},{"id":"5","value":"as of Oct 18, 2017, 08:34"},{"id":"6","value":"5"},{"id":"7","value":"720 x 1280"},{"id":"8","value":"32"},{"id":"9","value":"3"},{"id":"10","value":"8"},{"id":"11","value":"155"},{"id":"12","value":["2"]},{"id":"13","value":["SD Card"]},{"id":"14","value":"2700"},{"id":"15","value":"3"},{"id":"16","value":"Android"},{"id":"17","value":"45"}]","` I have seen other posts out there on the subject with a lot of confusing jargon for novices which never helped me solve my problem, I hope that this post can help others in my position who want a simple answer thanks.